# Best approach for scaling dimensions of text in HTML Canvas from pixels to inches

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I’m working on building something similar to https://lettering.com/create/ (think vinyl stickers)
I am currently using the HTML Canvas element. It’s doing what I need it to do without all the bells and whistles.

My question is if anyone has any thoughts on how to get dimensions from pixels to inches. With the Canvas, I can get the height/width in pixels of the text being displayed, but I cant seem to understand the equation to scale the text dependent on font. A tall and skinny font will obviously have different dimensions than a short and wide font.

If you go to the website on the Text & Size tab, you can adjust the height and width, along with maintaining proportions or not.

Any thoughts would be great! Or even if you may have an idea on how this specific site does theirs?

Comment: The text size is defined by the client eg 2 inch per letter. That size is then used to print (make hard copy). There is no such thing as pixel to inches as pixel size is not standardized. Each display can have its own unique pixel size (and or shape) The canvas has nothing to do with physical size.

Comment: @Blindman67 Sorry, I may have worded it weird with the pixels to inches. I understand it's not standardized across the board. I have the .ttf font file, but not sure how to figure out the correct height/width dimensions (in inches) when showing on the screen. I brought up the canvas due to having the dimensions of the font, and maybe being able to add some sort of multiplier to get a close size.

Comment: To scale text to match a print size you need to know the size and resolution of the display. There is no reliable way to know the size of the display, there are no APIs that provide that information. At best you can keep a (very long) list of all the displays and  sizes you expect clients to use and then ask the client to indicate which display they have, if they know, (with all the problems that entails)